# How to add social media icon to field in Odoo?

Tags: python, odoo

In my odoo app there is customer model. I need to create three new fields to hold the information about social media. I need three char fields (Facebook, LinkedIn Twitter), but  each one should be shown with the corresponding icon. How do I do that?

Comment: with your customize widget you can work around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

In your view ,

```html
<div>
    <field name="your_field"/><div class="fa fa-facebook"/>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont need the field to be binary to hold a picture. I need it to be char to hold the username of the facebook account. But in the view I need to show the facebook icon next to the field

Comment: @ErnestoRuiz. I update my answer.If label is not display for your field, add label for your field.